# Should it be possible to suspend a question **Pending a diagram**

Tags: feature-request

There are any number of questions asked where the description, or the formula, is still totally unclear without a diagram. For instance what's the impedance of an RLC circuit? Well OK, what configuration?

It may be appropriate to use the existing '5 votes to hold' process, but perhaps have an additional radio button there specifically for 'lacking a schematic diagram'. As the case is more clear cut, maybe fewer votes could necessary for that reason? Perhaps when held for that reason, the 'add a diagram' button could be highlighted in some way?

Could it possible for the system to automatically release a question when a diagram is added? This would avoid exacerbating the on hold release review queue situation. Or is that non-trivial server side code that's more trouble than it's worth? The system would not have to judge the quality of a diagram, I'm assuming that a totally inadequate one would be re-held by humans.

Answer (score 4):

This is what closing a question is for.  In theory, questions can be re-opened when the issues have been addressed, and sometimes that actually happens.

Re-opening automatically is a bad idea.  Often there is still much confusing, usually the root cause being a muddled thought process that no amount of diagrams is going to fix.  Often the schematic is a mess too.  This needs to be judged by humans, not machine.

I personally rarely vote to reopen because I don't like people coming here noising the site while they probe what they can get away with.  This isn't a game to see how little effort you can put into a question without it being closed.

If someone can't be bothered to read the rules and take a little care to write a clear questions, then *"Off with their heads!"* I say.